# Change specific 'for loop' structure to make the iteration faster

Tags: r, loops, append

This question is based on answers of question here:
[Join based on a concatenated 'origin-destination' variable and consecutive individual sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73207681/join-based-on-a-concatenated-origin-destination-variable-and-consecutive-indiv)

I have a for loop that needs to iterate over +100 thousand rows, and performs too slow. The main task is to iterate over each row of `pairs` and find the *Vonat_ID* variable in `STATIONS` dataframe, then with the `match` function find the stations in `STATIONS` that go from *HONNAN* variable to *HOVA* variable from the iterating row in `pairs`.

This is the pairs dataframe. (167 thousand rows)

```
 head(pairs)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Vonat_ID [2]
  Vonat_ID       HONNAN             HOVA            OD_pár                            
  <chr>          <chr>              <chr>           <chr>                             
1 20210216-40517 Hegyeshalom        Hegyeshalom oh. Hegyeshalom -- Hegyeshalom oh.    
2 20210216-40517 Biharkeresztes oh. Püspökladány    Biharkeresztes oh. -- Püspökladány
3 20210216-40517 Püspökladány       Hegyeshalom oh. Püspökladány -- Hegyeshalom oh.   
4 20210223-40517 Püspökladány       Ferencváros     Püspökladány -- Ferencváros       
5 20210223-40517 Biharkeresztes oh. Püspökladány    Biharkeresztes oh. -- Püspökladány
6 20210223-40517 Püspökladány       Hegyeshalom oh. Püspökladány -- Hegyeshalom oh.
```

This is the STATIONS dataframe. (2.7 millions rows)

```
head(STATIONS)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   Vonat_ID [1]
  Vonat_ID       Állomás           
  <chr>          <chr>             
1 20210216-40517 Biharkeresztes oh.
2 20210216-40517 Biharkeresztes    
3 20210216-40517 Mezőpeterd        
4 20210216-40517 Berettyóújfalu    
5 20210216-40517 Sáp               
6 20210216-40517 Báránd            
...
   20210216-40517 Öttevény                
55 20210216-40517 Lébény-Mosonszentmiklós 
56 20210216-40517 Kimle-Károlyháza        
57 20210216-40517 Mosonmagyaróvár         
58 20210216-40517 Hegyeshalom             
59 20210216-40517 Hegyeshalom oh.
60 20210223-40517 Biharkeresztes oh. 
61 20210223-40517 Biharkeresztes     
62 20210223-40517 Mezőpeterd         
63 20210223-40517 Berettyóújfalu     
64 20210223-40517 Sáp                
65 20210223-40517 Báránd             
...
88 20210223-40517 Öttevény               
89 20210223-40517 Lébény-Mosonszentmiklós
90 20210223-40517 Kimle-Károlyháza       
91 20210223-40517 Mosonmagyaróvár        
92 20210223-40517 Hegyeshalom            
93 20210223-40517 Hegyeshalom oh.
...
```

I created vectors of each variable from `pairs` to speed up the for loop. `pairs_ID`, `pairs_HN`, `pairs_HV` and `pairs_OD`, respectively.

The desired output looks like this: (*stat* is all the "Állomás" from `STATIONS` between the "OD_pár" starting and endpoint. (HONNAN means FROM, HOVA means TO))

```
                                  OD               stat
1     Hegyeshalom -- Hegyeshalom oh.       Hegyeshalom #"OD_pár" from the first row of `pairs`
2     Hegyeshalom -- Hegyeshalom oh.     Hegyeshalom oh.
3 Biharkeresztes oh. -- Püspökladány  Biharkeresztes oh.#"OD_pár" from the second row of `pairs`
4 Biharkeresztes oh. -- Püspökladány     Biharkeresztes
5 Biharkeresztes oh. -- Püspökladány         Mezőpeterd
6 Biharkeresztes oh. -- Püspökladány     Berettyóújfalu
```

The for loop I am using is the following.
I need a huge dataframe at the end with all the matching ODs and their station names, hence the list appending at the end of the loop. Also, I added an error catch function in case any appear.

```
bridge_total <- list()
for (x in 1:nrow(pairs)) {
tryCatch({
    OD <- pairs_OD[x]
    stat <- STATIONS[STATIONS$Vonat_ID==pairs_ID[x],][[2]][match(pairs_HN[x], STATIONS[STATIONS$Vonat_ID==pairs_ID[x],][[2]]) :
                   match(pairs_HV[x], STATIONS[STATIONS$Vonat_ID==pairs_ID[x],][[2]])]
    }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
  df <- data.frame("OD"=OD, "stat"=stat)
  bridge_total[[x]] <- df
  print(x)
}
bridge_total <- do.call(rbind, bridge_total)
```

Is there a way I could speed up the loop even better? right now as of test runs, to iterate over +100k rows, it requires 2-3 hours minimum.

Comment: I don't fully understand the description but I'm pretty sure you should use data.table  joins and not what you are using now.

Comment: drop the for-loop, start reading about joins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: @wimpel it is not a joining problem. Maybe the description is a bit unclear, but it's not simple joining what I need here

Comment: then i do not understand your question right. Can you provide a *minimal* sample dataset, and the desired output for this data?

Comment: @wimpel, tried to add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this small dataset should reproduce the setup:

```r
library(data.table)

journeys <- rbind(
  data.table(line = 1, origin = "A", destination = "C"),
  data.table(line = 2, origin = "B", destination = "E"),
  data.table(line = 2, origin = "D", destination = "E")
)

journeys
#>    line origin destination
#> 1:    1      A           C
#> 2:    2      B           E
#> 3:    2      D           E

stops <- rbind(
  data.table(line = 1, station = c("A", "B", "C")),
  data.table(line = 2, station = c("D", "B", "E"))
)

stops
#>    line station
#> 1:    1       A
#> 2:    1       B
#> 3:    1       C
#> 4:    2       D
#> 5:    2       B
#> 6:    2       E
```

And now the goal is to find all stops that constitute a journey.

Instead of looping, it may be faster to first use joins to find the origin
and destination indices in the `stops` data frame:

```r
setkey(journeys, line)
setkey(stops, line)

stops[, idx := .I]

journeys[stops, oidx := idx, on = .(line, origin = station)]
journeys[stops, didx := idx, on = .(line, destination = station)]
journeys[, len := 1L + didx - oidx]

journeys
#>    line origin destination oidx didx len
#> 1:    1      A           C    1    3   3
#> 2:    2      B           E    5    6   2
#> 3:    2      D           E    4    6   3
```

Then extract the corresponding stops:

```r
journeys[, cbind(journey = rep(.I, len), stops[sequence(len, oidx)])]
#>    journey line station idx
#> 1:       1    1       A   1
#> 2:       1    1       B   2
#> 3:       1    1       C   3
#> 4:       2    2       B   5
#> 5:       2    2       E   6
#> 6:       3    2       D   4
#> 7:       3    2       B   5
#> 8:       3    2       E   6
```

Comment: perfect, many thanks! You just nailed it! Since there are some 'lines' that are not present in journeys, not all values could be extracted, but it is just a matter of data cleanness. Appreciate! from hours to 3 seconds